# Which is better in lens hoods, felt-like material or sawtooth surface?

Tags: optics, lens-hood

I have noticed that many<sup>1</sup> Canon lens hoods contain a felt-like matte black material designed to reduce reflections. The material probably does so admirably, but tends to get dusty over time.

On the other hand, third party lenses like Tamron have a sawtooth plastic inner surface in the lens hood. An immediate benefit is that dust doesn't stick to this sawtooth surface.

Does the sawtooth plastic inner surface work acceptably to reduce reflections? Is it equal or worse (or better) in terms of image quality when compared to Canon's felt-like matte black material?

(1): I looked again at my lens hoods, and indeed, the cheap 50mm "nifty fifty" lens hood does not have this material. It even does not have a sawtooth surface. But it's a cheap lens, probably Canon's cheapest.

Comment: Not all Canon hoods use felt.

Comment: Telephoto prime? Very wide angle zoom? Etc.?

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be full proof of the acceptability of the textured sawtooth surface, but today I swapped my EF 24-105mm lens for an RF 24-105mm lens.

The RF 24-105mm lens hood has the textured sawtooth surface and not the felt-like material I'm used to seeing in Canon lens hoods.

If someone complains that "professionals use 24-70 and not 24-105 and thus this doesn't demonstrate anything", similarly, the EW-88E lens hood for RF 24-70mm f/2.8 lens has the sawtooth surface. Also, the ET-83F hood for the RF 70-200 f/2.8 uses the sawtooth surface.

It appears Canon is switching to the textured sawtooth surface in its top-of-the-line lenses. I assume this is mainly due to collecting less dust and being easier to blow the dust away rather than some image quality improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that the felt is better at absorbing light. But I have never had an issue with the textured surface being insufficient with my Sigma lenses.